# "ajax" call in jQuery fires "success" function even when server does not respond

Tags: jquery, ajax

It looks like jQuery's `.ajax` function fires the `'success'` function even when it gets no response from the server.  I'd consider this an error.  I detected this event by checking to see if the `'request.status===0'`, are there any other instances that I should check for where the `'success'` function will be fired even if there is an error situation?

I've posted the code I'm using now below.  How is this type of situation normally handled?

```
$.ajax({ 
    async : true, cache : false, dataType : 'json',
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'person/' + personKey,
    data : JSON.stringify({firstName:'Jilopi',}),

    success : function(data, textStatus, request){
        if( request.status === 0 ){
            alert('Error: problem saving person - no response');
        }else{
            alert('Success: saved person');
        }
    },
    error : function(request, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('Error: problem saving person');
    },
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "no response", the response timing out? What does Firebug report about the response?

Comment: By the way, the trailing comma after `error` (and possibly the one in `data`) will break in IE

Comment: Firebug indicates an error.  The response and response headers are blank.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've identified the only "false success" issue I know of.  To elaborate on it a bit: this was a work-around in place strictly for Opera (which returns what's *actually* a `304` as a `0`), you can see the comment in **1.4.2** (and prior versions) here: http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/ajax.js#L551

However, [it has been removed in jQuery 1.4.3 because of your exact issue](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.3/src/ajax.js#L637), you can see [the change that did it here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/dc8491defe5360afe076249a696f72f73a96dc23).

*Short answer:* upgrade to [jQuery 1.4.3+](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery) to resolve your issue and you can do away with your `status === 0` check.

Answer (score 0):

I also had some need to show if the ES Server is online or not!
**My Solution in words:**

> I used long polling to check my server status! And ES Already have a
>   REST API Call just to get the information about the ES Server!
>
> That's Cluster Health request!

[Read about ES Cluster Health Requests here!](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html)

Just type the following on your Web Browser and see the response of it about your ES Server!

```
http://your-server-url:9200/_cluster/health
```

**Simple jQuery long-polling recursive function snippet:**

```
(function poll(){
health_url = "http://your-server-url:9200/_cluster/health";
online_ajax = false;
setTimeout(function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: health_url,
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
            if (data.status == 'yellow') {
                // Show Server-Online Status Message in your App
            } else {
                // Show Server-Offline Status Message in your App
            };
            //Setup the next poll recursively
            poll();
          }
      })
      .fail(function(){
            // Show Server-Offline Status Message in your App
      });
}, online_status_time_out);
})();
```

Hope this answer is helpful to everyone!

Cheers!!!